# MySQL append data to each JSON Object within JSON Array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, aggregate-functions

in this table - `mytable` i have a json column - `col` and its content
`[{"id": 1, "data1": "abc", "data2": "xyz"}, {"id": 2, "data1": "def", "data2": "ghi"}]`

there is an another table - `product`

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | pro 1   |
+----+---------+
|  2 | pro 2   |
+----+---------+
```

is there a way that I can append name to each JSON Object in the JSON Array
Ex- `[{"id": 1,"name":"pro 1", "data1": "abc", "data2": "xyz"}, {"id": 2,"name":"pro 2", "data1": "def", "data2": "ghi"}]`

Comment: Split the array to separate objects, join with additional data table, update objects, join the array back.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: What does `select version();` show?  And do you want to modify what's in mytable.col or just select with name added?

Comment: @Akina mysql 5.7

Comment: @ysth just a select with name added !

Comment: The version is too old. The query will be too complex. I'd recommend to upgrade the server. If not then create iterational stored procedure.

Comment: 8.0 makes this so much easier

Comment: @ysth any solutions for 8.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use `json_table()` for this. The idea is to unnest the json array to rows, join the `product` table and then re-aggregate.

```
select json_arrayagg(
    json_object(
        'id',    x.id,
        'data1', x.data1,
        'data2', x.data2,
        'name',  p.name
    )
) as col
from mytable t
cross join json_table(
    t.col, 
    '$[*]' columns ('id' int, 'data1' varchar(50), 'data2' varchar(50))
) x
inner join product p on p.id = x.id
group by x.id
```